# Скрытие пустых полей

Tags: xml, php

С помощью php вывожу данные из xml-ки:

```
На рынке жилья затишье
Поведение рынка недвижимости в прошлом году было довольно нестандартным. Наверное, этим объясняются противоречивые прогнозы, которые давали специалисты на текущий год. Какова же реальная ситуация на рынке жилья сегодня? Об этом рассказывает руководитель д

Автор:
```

При этом данные об авторе в xml отсутствуют... Как сделать так, чтобы автор не выводился (чтобы обработка тега <p> не проходила)?
Вывод данных об авторе осуществляется следующим образом:

```
<p>Автор: <?=$sAutorArticle?></p>
```

т.е. с помощью html и php. 
Реализовал в php возможность скрытия пустых тегов с помощью LIBXML_NOBLANKS.
Тем не менее строка автор является html-ой и в любом случае будет выводиться, даже если соответствующий ей тег отсутствует.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($sAutorArticle != "") echo'<p>Автор: '.$sAutorArticle.'</p>';
```

Comment: <p>Автор: <?=$sAutorArticle?></p> все равно обрабатывается. Можно как-нибудь при проверке условия: 
if($sAutorArticle != "") echo'<p>Автор: '.$sAutorArticle.'</p>';
отключить тег <p> вывода текста об авторе?

Comment: заменить нужно вывод так как я написал

Comment: а все понял)) спс))

Answer (score 0):

```
if($sAutorArticle == "") { автора нет (нет <p>) } else { автор есть (есть <p>) }
```